# How to prove that optimization problem solution is/is not differentiable with respect to constraint variable?

Tags: optimization, constraints

Assume you have the following simple constrained optimization problem:

$$h(c)=\min_{g(x)=c} f(x)$$

where $f,g$ are both differentiable.

What are the standard way to show that the problem solution $h(c)$ is/is not differentiable with respect to $c$? I have run a few concrete examples and found that numerically the solution seems to be differentiable, but I have no idea how to show it more formally.

Would appreciate conditions/properties that I can use to prove this statement to be true/untrue! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that $h$ is differentiable.

Consider, for example, $g(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=x$.  Then $h(c)=-\sqrt{c}$ for $c \ge 0$ and $h(c)=+\infty$ for $c<0$.  This is not differentiable at $c=0$.

One special case: if $g$ is strictly monotonic (i.e., strictly increasing or strictly decreasing), then $h$ will be differentiable.

Comment: Sorry but how is $h(c) =$ positive infinity when $c<0$? Isn't the function not defined for $c<0$ because there is no $x$ which satisfies $g(x)=c$ in this case?

Comment: @czl, the minimum of an empty set is frequently taken to be $+\infty$, as a matter of convention.  Of course it is up to you how you want to define your function, as long as you are clear in the specification of $f$.

Comment: Thanks, how would it formally show the special case:  if $g$
 is strictly monotonic (i.e., strictly increasing or strictly decreasing), then $h$
 will be differentiable? Intuitively it seems correct, but is there a way to show it rigorously?